# jQuery - How to select hidden/visible elements?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do multistep form, and I have 5 div's (all of them hidden) 
The five of them are parts of a form so I can get the first and the last div by doing this

```
  var first = $("#new").children(":first").next();
  var last = $("#back").prev('div');
```

"#new" is the id of the form, and "#back" the id of the back button.
After click on the NEXT button it shows first.next(); , but it should only work the first time then it should display the next() of the div that is visible.

How can I get that div?

Thanks

EDIT:
I'm trying to do this because after I click next on the first div
then it shows the second div, and after that the third an so on,
but I want to do a function where it automatically detects wich one is visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question got a bit confusing but if you want to check if an element is visible then you can use the `:hidden` pseudo selector:

```
var first = $("#new").children(":first").nextAll(':hidden');
```

And to find only visible elements:

```
var first = $("#new").children(":first").nextAll(':visible');
```

Docs for `:hidden`: http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Docs for `:visible`: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v8fKc/

Notice I used `.nextAll()` instead of `.next()` because the latter only looks for the single next element and the former looks at all the sibling elements that come after the root selection.

Docs for `.nextAll()`: http://api.jquery.com/nextall

Comment: is there a way to filter only the div's? because if I do that it also gives me some <p> that I have in between

Comment: @JavierQQ23 add the tag-name to the selector: `var first = $("#new").children("div:first").nextAll('div:visible');`. I generally don't do this because it slows down the selectors but if you have a good reason then it's there to use.

Comment: Thanks!, I only wanted to filter the div's in nextAll :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#theid:visible').length > 0)
     console.log('I Am Visible');
else
     console.log('I Am Not Visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

give a whirl:

```
 $(this).is(':visible');
```