# Select visible elements not hidden by overflow: hidden parent

Tags: jquery

I have a overflow: hidden div that contains several other divs that may or may not be hidden depending on the size of the browser window. Is there a way I can select only the visible child divs using jQuery?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/checking-if-an-element-is-hidden?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823652/jquery-how-to-select-hidden-visible-elements?rq=1

Comment: use the width of the div, and then the css property of the elements "left" value, relative to the divs left value. If it is within the width, then it is visible. like div is 80px and 5px left. if the element is 90px from left, it is hidden, if not, it is visible. If you need an example of the logic, i can write one up.